# Django: how to add http header to responses in a convenient way?

Tags: python, django, http, web

I know we can use `HttpResponseInstance['headername'] = 'headervalue'` to add header to http response. But in this way, I have to rewrite all the generic view I am using, which makes much more work.

Is there a convenient way to add header to responses, like a callback for responses, or a url decorator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/middleware/) class and implement the method [`process_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/middleware/#process-response).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a middleware class. [Check out this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36099405)

Django 1.10 and above `__init__` and `__call__` should be implement. `process_response` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function you can run that can replace "render" so that it includes the response headers assignments without needing to repeat the value assignments to the different response headers. This is probably useful if you don't want to repeat your code and you want to apply the changes to some, but not all views. Below is specifically a function that makes sure the rendering doesn't cache:

```
def render_cacheless(action, path, context):
    response = render(action, path, context)
    response["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response["Expires"] = "0"

    return response

def home(request):
    return render_cacheless(request, "/path/to/home.html", None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some custom headers when returning JsonResponse.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

data = {'key','value'} # some data

response = JsonResponse(data,status=200)

response['Retry-after'] = 345 # seconds 
response['custom-header'] = 'some value'

return response
```