# How to add an HTTP header to all Django responses

Tags: django, http, http-headers

I'd like to add a few headers to all responses that my Django website returns. Is there a way to do this (besides adding a wrapper to the `render` function)?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Yes, you should have a look at [middlewares](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/middleware/).

*yourapp/middleware.py*

```
class MyMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        response['X-My-Header'] = "my value"
        return response
```

*yourproject/settings.py*

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    'yourapp.middleware.MyMiddleware',
    ...,
]
```

Answer (score 3):

When returning JsonResponse.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

data = {'key','value'} # some data

response = JsonResponse(data,status=200)

response['Retry-after'] = 345 # seconds 
response['custom-header'] = 'some value'

return response
```