# Python is there a way to read custom headers and send a response back

Tags: python, django, http

Ok so I am new to python as a whole. That said I don't know what I'm really looking for to ask this question properly. I know this has to be possible though. I want to ask this before really digging in and finding out I did something wrong and have to do it all over.

All in all what I want to know is, from the front end of my stack I want to pass down custom HTTP headers (which I can do with my Ajax calls, currently). The question is how do I actually read said headers? Similarly how can I pass back up from the server custom headers via python.

Comment: For django: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099244/how-to-add-an-http-header-to-all-django-responses

Answer (score 2):

You can access custom header in Django view:

```
request.META.get("Custom_Header")
```

Answer (score 1):

For django:
[How to add an HTTP header to all Django responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099244/how-to-add-an-http-header-to-all-django-responses)

You can definitely do it in the front end. You can do it with Javascript's native [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), the newer [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), or some other library (like [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)).