# Cache control in Nginx+Django

Tags: django, nginx, django-cache, waitress, nginx-cache

I have a server on *Nginx*. It is written with *Django* and connected to *Nginx* through *Waitress*. I have set up a cache in *Nginx*. My server has both dynamic and static pages.

After starting a server, it caches only static pages(correct behaviour for me), but I also want it to have a Cache-Control header in HTTP-request(I need Cache-Control no-store, to not cache anything at all), but it doesn't.

I don't understand how to set up Cache-Control(**no-store**) header, because when I try to write it into *Nginx's* config file, then although this header appears in HTTP-request(in *Postman*), *Nginx* ignores it and continues caching into my cache folder(i.e. proxy_cache_path). So, I think, that I need somehow to put Cache-Control header into Django itself.

My **nginx.conf** file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    include C:/Users/User/Desktop/BDUTS/nginx_server/sites-enabled/locallibrary.conf;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       10;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```

Included **locallibrary.conf** file:

```
# CACHE
proxy_cache_path cache/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:32m;

# cache-proxy
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri:u:$cookie_user";
        proxy_cache_valid any 10s;
        proxy_cache cache;
    }
}

server{
    listen 8080;

    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }
}
```

It's **runserver.py** file to run server with *Waitress*:

```
#runserver.py
from waitress import serve

from locallibrary.wsgi import application
print("Starting server...")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(application, host='127.0.0.1', port='8080')
```

So, I have a main question. **How to correctly add Cache-Control header to my server and make it be taken into account by Nginx?**

I've tried next:

1. To put `add_header Cache-Control no-store;` in locallibrary.conf after `proxy_cache cache;` line in `#cahce-proxy`. It doesn't work, because, in my opinion, it added Cache-Control header only after sending answer to client already. So, it doesn't go to the *Django* at all.
2. I think, that I need somehow to control headers with *Django*, but found nothing in *Django's* source folder and project folder.

Comment: Use the HttpResponse object https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099244/how-to-add-an-http-header-to-all-django-responses) topic answered my question.